# How to hotplug interface by libvirtd?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I'm trying to hotplug a interface to a running domain by the following command :

```
bash-4.4# virsh attach-interface 1 --type network --source net1 --model virtio-non-transitional --target /sys/devices/virtual/net/net1/tap603053 --mac  ac:de:48:77:a2:32 --config --live
Authorization not available. Check if polkit service is running or see debug message for more information.
error: Failed to attach interface
error: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/virtnetworkd-sock': No such file or directory
```

As you can see, I got the error upon.

According to [libvirt daemons](https://libvirt.org/daemons.html), there's two arch which is "Monolithic daemon" and "modular daemon". So I think if I use the "Monolithic daemon" to hotplug an interface then virsh will not connect to `virtnetworkd` but `libvirtd`(libvirtd is exist). So I change the command to the following :

```
bash-4.4# virsh -c qemu:///system attach-interface 1 --type network --source net1 --model virtio-non-transitional --target /sys/devices/virtual/net/net1/tap603053 --mac  ac:de:48:77:a2:32 --config --live
Authorization not available. Check if polkit service is running or see debug message for more information.
error: Failed to attach interface
error: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/virtnetworkd-sock': No such file or directory
```

As you can see I still got the error same with first command.

My question is : how should I hotplug an interface without virtnetworkd running ?

Answer (score 0):

Without `virnetworkd` you will not be able to define any interface backed by a libvirt-managed network (e.g. those in the output of `virsh net-list` on a host which has `virtnetworkd). This means that` --type network` will not work.

Nevertheless you can use other modes which do not require `virtnetwork` such as described by the following documentation bits:

https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#direct-attachment-to-physical-interface

https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#bridge-to-lan

https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#userspace-slirp-or-passt-connection

https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#generic-ethernet-connection

Note that you need to decide yourself which mode you want to use and your description does not provide enough information for me to suggest one.